# unable to send mail through php mail() function getting exception - Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: web-services, web-deployment

Even after two days of continuous trials.. I am stuck with "mail sending failed" error

**Although many solutions are there on stack overflow itself but I am still asking this becoz none of them helped**

*Pre--(if required)
Using WINDOWS 10 ,php 5.5.12 ,apache 2.4.9*

**My approach**

1) downloaded smtp

2) configured smtp.ini

3) configured php.ini

4) configured my gmail account

**Note**
I have tried all possible approaches and more than 15 tutorials till now to get this mail thing done in last 2 days...

but :(
**also I have set my gmail account to allow less secure apps , enabled IMAP and disbled 2 step verification**

I am enclosing the error log files and my smtp and php.ini files

```
configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=none

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=localhost

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=myid@gmail.com
auth_password=mypasswordhere

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=myid@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost
```

**I am getting the following error log**

```
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** To: somenath@gmail.com
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** Subject: Testing sendmail.exe
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:tt1.php
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** From: myid@gmail.com
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** MIME-Version: 1.0
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** 
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
16/03/19 09:44:36 ** Connected.
16/03/19 09:44:37 << 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP wx3sm24328300pab.25 - gsmtp<EOL>
16/03/19 09:44:37 >> EHLO localhost<EOL>
16/03/19 09:44:37 << 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [115.248.50.20]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
16/03/19 09:44:37 ** Authenticating as myid@gmail.com
16/03/19 09:44:37 >> MAIL FROM: <myid@gmail.com><EOL>
16/03/19 09:44:37 << 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. wx3sm24328300pab.25 - gsmtp<EOL>
16/03/19 09:44:37 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
16/03/19 09:44:37 ** Disconnected.
16/03/19 09:44:37 ** Disconnected.
16/03/19 09:44:37 ** Must issue a STARTTLS command first. wx3sm24328300pab.25 - gsmtp<EOL>
```

**here is the snippet of php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = myid.1994@gmail.com



; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;mail.log = syslog
```

**4) my php code**

```
<?php

$to       = 'somenath@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: myid@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config:

```
smtp_ssl=none
```

You're turning off the very thing that you need. You're using port 587 (as you should), so you need to set `smtp_ssl=auto` or `smtp_ssl=tls`.

[This comment in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#118210) shows how to set user id and password properties.

Comment: Hey Synchro,
thanks for reply...but as I mentioned in my question that  I have tried each and every possible trick.
I mean ,I have tried smtp_ssl=auto and smtp_ssl=tls
but none of them have worked..
please point out something else ...
(if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

**Finally got it working**
For those fellows who have almost given up ,just like I had, after 48 hours of tries :( 
Here is something which you should cherish

**do everything as I have posted above in my question**

ie

1) download smtp

2) configure smtp.ini

3) configure php.ini

4) configure your gmail account

5) also set your gmail account to allow less secure apps , enable IMAP and disble 2 step verification

**make sure you do these**

--**smtp_ssl=none**
to 
**smtp_ssl=ssl**

and

**smtp_port=587**
to
**smtp_port=465**

Now ***Most important*** thing that was the problem in my case

I had not configured my sendmail.exe...

so
**DO this**

1) go to sendmail folder where you have your sendmail.exe

2)right click on sendmail.exe -->then properties

3)go compatibilty tab

4) change compatability for all users

5) tick run as admin

6) and most importantly, under compatibilty mode ***select windows service pack 3***

7) apply and done

hope it helps

comment if you face any problem :)

Comment: You should favour port 587 with tls over 465 with ssl.

Comment: Because SMTPS (SSL on 465) was deprecated in 1998, and only sticks around because crummy Microsoft products didn't get the memo.